# Adding Fira Code on either emacs < 27 or emacs >= 27

Tags: fonts, prettify-symbols-mode

There's a thing I really never understood in emacs, and it comes to changing the default font. I tried following this tutorial to add Fira Code to emacs: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Emacs-instructions (the Using Prettify Symbols part that I copy/pasted at the end of this question after the horizontal rule)

So, in my emacs I have the following lines:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foundry "unknown" :slant normal :weight normal :height 113 :width normal :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil)))))

(use-package fira-code-mode
  :hook prog-mode)
```

I have all the fonts installed:

```
❯ fc-list | grep -i "fira"
/usr/local/share/fonts/f/FiraCode_Regular_Symbol.otf: Fira Code Symbol:style=Symbol-Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/firacode/FiraCode-Retina.otf: Fira Code,Fira Code Retina:style=Retina,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/firacode/FiraCode-Bold.otf: Fira Code:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/firacode/FiraCode-Regular.otf: Fira Code:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/firacode/FiraCode-Medium.otf: Fira Code,Fira Code Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/firacode/FiraCode-Light.otf: Fira Code,Fira Code Light:style=Light,Regular
```

But `->` will be displayed as `[`, for example (`==` is displayed as `⊇`)

I then followed this update: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/211#issuecomment-560148847

But even though the displayed symbols are not the same, they're still not what I expect to have (meaning that == is not displayed as == with a ligature as described on the FiraCode github page (https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) but: [image], for example)

In a last attempt I installed emacs 27 by cloning the repository but I can't figure out how to make it accept the ligatures from Fira Code so I have the exact same behaviour and actually start to despair having ligatures in emacs.

---

Copy/paste of the tutorial

Using prettify-symbols

These instructions are pieced together by @Triavanicus, taking some pieces from: Hasklig-Mode.

This method requires you to install the Fira Code Symbol font, made by @siegebell: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/211#issuecomment-239058632

```
(defun fira-code-mode--make-alist (list)
  "Generate prettify-symbols alist from LIST."
  (let ((idx -1))
    (mapcar
     (lambda (s)
       (setq idx (1+ idx))
       (let* ((code (+ #Xe100 idx))
          (width (string-width s))
          (prefix ())
          (suffix '(?\s (Br . Br)))
          (n 1))
     (while (< n width)
       (setq prefix (append prefix '(?\s (Br . Bl))))
       (setq n (1+ n)))
     (cons s (append prefix suffix (list (decode-char 'ucs code))))))
     list)))

(defconst fira-code-mode--ligatures
  '("www" "**" "***" "**/" "*>" "*/" "\\\\" "\\\\\\"
    "{-" "[]" "::" ":::" ":=" "!!" "!=" "!==" "-}"
    "--" "---" "-->" "->" "->>" "-<" "-<<" "-~"
    "#{" "#[" "##" "###" "####" "#(" "#?" "#_" "#_("
    ".-" ".=" ".." "..<" "..." "?=" "??" ";;" "/*"
    "/**" "/=" "/==" "/>" "//" "///" "&&" "||" "||="
    "|=" "|>" "^=" "$>" "++" "+++" "+>" "=:=" "=="
    "===" "==>" "=>" "=>>" "<=" "=<<" "=/=" ">-" ">="
    ">=>" ">>" ">>-" ">>=" ">>>" "<*" "<*>" "<|" "<|>"
    "<$" "<$>" "<!--" "<-" "<--" "<->" "<+" "<+>" "<="
    "<==" "<=>" "<=<" "<>" "<<" "<<-" "<<=" "<<<" "<~"
    "<~~" "</" "</>" "~@" "~-" "~=" "~>" "~~" "~~>" "%%"
    "x" ":" "+" "+" "*"))

(defvar fira-code-mode--old-prettify-alist)

(defun fira-code-mode--enable ()
  "Enable Fira Code ligatures in current buffer."
  (setq-local fira-code-mode--old-prettify-alist prettify-symbols-alist)
  (setq-local prettify-symbols-alist (append (fira-code-mode--make-alist fira-code-mode--ligatures) fira-code-mode--old-prettify-alist))
  (prettify-symbols-mode t))

(defun fira-code-mode--disable ()
  "Disable Fira Code ligatures in current buffer."
  (setq-local prettify-symbols-alist fira-code-mode--old-prettify-alist)
  (prettify-symbols-mode -1))

(define-minor-mode fira-code-mode
  "Fira Code ligatures minor mode"
  :lighter " Fira Code"
  (setq-local prettify-symbols-unprettify-at-point 'right-edge)
  (if fira-code-mode
      (fira-code-mode--enable)
    (fira-code-mode--disable)))

(defun fira-code-mode--setup ()
  "Setup Fira Code Symbols"
  (set-fontset-font t '(#Xe100 . #Xe16f) "Fira Code Symbol"))

(provide 'fira-code-mode)
```

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you want/expect versus what you see. You say *"But even though the displayed symbols are not the same, they're still not what I expect to have."* That's not clear to me. What are the displayed symbols, and what did you expect them to be? Try to ask your question as a question - that will help.

Comment: I edited my question to show what is displayed when using the second method.